# Как посчитать вложенный count для родителя?

Tags: php, массивы

Столкнулся с проблемой. Не знаю, как родителю присвоить "COUNT" потомков. То есть из такого массива

```
$array = [
    100245 => [
        'name' => 'Name 1',
        'cnt' => 0
        'child' => [
            205245 => [
                'name' => 'Name 3',
                'cnt' => 0
                'child' => [
                    100245 => [
                        'name' => 'Name 5',
                        'cnt' => 3
                        'child' => []
                    ],
                    100277 => [
                        'name' => 'Name 6',
                        'cnt' => 7
                        'child' => []
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    100115 => [
        'name' => 'Name 2',
        'cnt' => 0
        'child' => [
            201245 => [
                'name' => 'Name 4',
                'cnt' => 0
                'child' => []
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Сделать такой

```
$array = [
    100245 => [
        'name' => 'Name 1',
        'cnt' => 22
        'child' => [
            205245 => [
                'name' => 'Name 3',
                'cnt' => 22
                'child' => [
                    100245 => [
                        'name' => 'Name 5',
                        'cnt' => 15
                        'child' => []
                    ],
                    100277 => [
                        'name' => 'Name 6',
                        'cnt' => 7
                        'child' => []
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    100115 => [
        'name' => 'Name 2',
        'cnt' => 0
        'child' => [
            201245 => [
                'name' => 'Name 4',
                'cnt' => 0
                'child' => []
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Можете скинуть валидный массив. там синтаксические ошибки + дублирование ключей.

Comment: Что вы уже сделали для решения вашего вопроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Черновой вариант решения

```
function countArrays(array $array): array
{
    foreach ($array['child'] as $key => $childArray) {
        $childArray = countArrays($childArray);
        $array['child'][$key] = $childArray;
        $array['cnt'] += $childArray['cnt'];
    }

    return $array;
}

foreach ($array as $key => $array2) {
    $array[$key] = countArrays($array2);
}
```

Comment: Вроде рабочий. Если, что завтра Ваш ответ лучшим поставлю. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать рекурсивную функцию:

```
function recursiveCount(&$array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$val) {     
        if ($val['child'] and is_array($val['child'])) {
            $c = recursiveCount($val['child']);
            $val['cnt'] = $c;
        }
        $count += $val['cnt'];

    }
    return $count;
}

recursiveCount($array);

print_r($array);
```

Рабочий код можно посмотреть здесь: [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=00dedfda293cf740e0daf3069ae01270&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)